# How can i add new tag synonym?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I want to add new tag-synonym for some tag's but i don't have any option to do this.
When i visit any tag there is a option for see all synonyms for that tag but not option to add new synonyms.

Please any one  tell me how can i add this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Create Tag Synonyms privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms.

To suggest synonym go to the tagged question page (i.e. click on any tag) > click on `synonyms(N)`

[image]

You will be redirected to the synonym page: `https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mytag/synonyms`

Here you can suggest synonyms if you have enough privilege and score on that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal - Your question is *how can I* not *who can*.